# Weather widget doesn't work since today

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've followed this tutorial : http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Creating-a-Weather-Widget-with-XML-and-AS3/43273

and everything was working great until today.

I've got this error : `Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://xoap.weather.com/weather/local/NCXX0006?cc=*&link=xoap&par=&key=&unit=m`

It seems that weather.com has changed something that makes this error.

I even downloaded the source files of the tutorial and test the .fla file and same error.

Any idea how can we fix this ?

Thank you,

Comment: Please add the relevant code directly to your question. No one will download and debug some 3rd-party source to answer your question.

Comment: How does it work if you call the same service from Fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

xoap.weather.com is down.  That is why its not working.  I assume it will come back sometime.  Just be patient.

Comment: Not quite sure is a "down" thing.. I'm afraid that is permanent (and now they only use weather.com instead of xoap.weather.com). That's what worries me...

Answer (score 0):

Use the XML version of the feed instead. Not sure why they disabled the XOAP domain but this should have the same information:

http://xml.weather.com/weather/local/NCXX0006?cc=*&link=xoap&par=&key=&unit=m